# Build a highchart chart using data from an external JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I'm trying to read a JSON file in a highcharts chart using JQuery but I failed. I've got this JSON in a file:

```
[{"Bellman-Ford": {"totalRate": 1.123, "way": [], "time": 0.00014495849609375}}, {"genetic": {"totalRate": 1.4566, "way": [], "time": 0.1541710883}}, {"recuit": {"totalRate": 1.782, "way": [], "time": 0.00004728945}}]
```

And my chart is like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#rate').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Comparison of the final rates'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'DNF'
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rate (USD)'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        animation : true,
        series: [{
            name: 'Bellman-Ford',
            data: [49.9] //bf rate

        }, {
            name: 'Genetic Algorithm',
            data: [83.6] // genetic rate

        }, {
            name: 'Recuit',
            data: [34.6] // recuit rate

        }]
    });
});
```

Instead of those hardcoded data, I want to use data from the JSON. The rate data from each algorithm (genetic, simulated annealing and bellman-ford). I think I didn't catch well the problem of asynchronous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We retrieve the JSON, which is automatically parsed by jQuery
2. We loop through the main array to get the objects using `for of` to access the objects directly
3. We loop though the object using `for in` to access the property names and then the data itself

The data and the chart are built after the JSON is received, using the `done()` method of [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```js
$(function () {

    // get the json
    $.ajax({
        url:      "result.json",
        dataType: "json",
    }).done(function(myData) {

        // initialize the data array
        var mySeries = [];

        // loop through the objects
        for(var myObj of myData) {

            // loop through the object's properties (seemingly only one)
            for(var myName in myObj) {

                // build data
                mySeries.push({
                    name : myName,
                    data : [myObj[myName].totalRate],
                });
            }
        }

        $('#rate').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Comparison of the final rates'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'DNF'
            },

            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Rate (USD)'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            animation : true,
            series: mySeries
        });
    });
});
```

Then we can use that in the chart options:

```
series: mySeries
```

### Update 2015-09-23 15:35 +0000

This is a quick note addressing the comments to this answer.

In a comment, OP said:

> I've got a syntax error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier: for(var myObj of myData) {

Another comment then said:

> Change: `for(var myObj of myData) {..}` to `for(var myObj in myData) {..}`

Using `for...in` iterates over the indexes rather than the values, this necessitates to use `myData[myObj]` to access the underlying object. There also was a time when using `for...in` on an array returned its length property, which was undesirable and required to use `for(var i=0; i<array.length; ++i)`.

More details in the MDN documentation:

- [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)
- [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: What if my json is in a file

Comment: @mel You would need to request it first using `xmlHttpRequest` or `jQuery.ajax()`.

Comment: I've got a syntax error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier:
for(var myObj of myData) {

Comment: @mel I can't reproduce that error on my end. Malformed JSON perhaps ? Or the code has been wrongly copied.

Comment: Change:  `for(var myObj of myData) {..}` to `for(var myObj in myData) {..}`

Answer (score 1):

**Update**  Code with fetching data from json file

```
  $(function () {
  var data =[];  
  $.getJSON("results.json", function(json) {

 $.each(json, function(idx, obj){ 
    $.each(obj, function(key, value){            
        data.push({name:key , data: [value.totalRate]});
    });
   });
     });
   $('#rate').highcharts({
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
title: {
    text: 'Comparison of the final rates'
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'DNF'
},

yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Rate (USD)'
    }
},
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0
    }
 },
 animation : true,
 series:data 
});
});
```

Use following code if your json data is in same page as JavaScript variable

```
var data =[];
var json = [{"Bellman-Ford":{"totalRate":1.123,"way":[],"time":0.00014495849609375}},{"genetic":{"totalRate":1.4566,"way":[],"time":0.1541710883}},{"recuit":{"totalRate":1.782,"way":[],"time":0.00004728945}}];

   $.each(json, function(idx, obj){ 
    $.each(obj, function(key, value){            
        data.push({name:key , data: [value.totalRate]});
    });
 });
```

See working [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/fsb2wyjw/2/)

Its always nice to have  json to be formatted when you fetch it from server. There should not be much processing on UI/javascript.

Comment: Yeah but my JSON is in another file

Comment: are you saying about json format I said above ? or you want to ask how to fetch?

Comment: use   $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("your json path here", function(json) { put my function and highchart in it});

Comment: The JSON is in a file result.json and the javascript is in another file chart.js

Comment: use like :   $.getJSON("results.json", function(json) {
    
 $.each(json, function(idx, obj){ 
        $.each(obj, function(key, value){            
            data.push({name:key , data: [value.totalRate]});
        });
    });
     }

Comment: @mel See updated fiddle with how to get json froma file , replace your code by this fiddle. put your results.json's path carefully http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/fsb2wyjw/4/